# Variable in file-audio.html.twig

Tags: theming

I created the following preprocess function to add a value.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node__audio(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $media_field = $node->get('field_image')->entity->uri->value;
  $variables['poster'] = file_create_url($media_field);
}
```

I want to output the content of `$variables['poster']` in the *file-audio.html.twig* template.

```
<audio {{ attributes }} poster="{{ poster }}">
  {% for file in files %}
    <source {{ file.source_attributes }} />
  {% endfor %}
</audio>
```

`{{ poster }}` outputs an empty string. I have tried multiple methods, with no success.

I can get the variable in the field template (*field--field-audio.html.twig*), but it is not available to the child file template I am using.

How do I get the value of `$variables['poster']` in the template file I am using?

Comment: `mytheme_preprocess_node__audio()` is a node preprocess function. If *file-audio.html.twig* is not a node template file used for the same content type, what set in `mytheme_preprocess_node__audio()` will not be available in *file-audio.html.twig*. From the question is not clear for what the *file-audio.html.twig* template is used.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno, i've tried preprocessing other scopes but I need a different field from the field that I am working on (trying to join two fields data together) so I'm not sure what the scope should be - what I should be preporcessing?
The file-audio.html.twig is a child twig template for the audio field and I can't figure out the scope to get a variable into it...

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out, it was not straightforward or obvious, and I could find no forum or post detailing this method, so hopefully it helps others.
The preprocess function changes to preprocess field as:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(array &$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];

  switch ($element['#field_name']) {
    // Machine name of the field
    case 'field_audio':
      $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
      // separate field (machine name = field_image) that holds image for poster
      $media_field = $node->get('field_image')->entity->uri->value; 
      $variables['poster'] = file_create_url($media_field);
      break;
  }
}
```

Then in the field twig file (field--field-audio.html.twig), replace the appropriate item.content section (or all of them as I did, just in case!)

```
      {% set attr = item.content['#attributes']|merge({'poster': poster}) %}
      {% set mycontent = item.content|merge({'#attributes': attr}) %}

      <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item') }}> {{ mycontent }} </div>
```

Finally in the file-audio.html.twig template you just need to add the poster="{{poster}}" like:

```
<audio {{ attributes }} style="background: transparent url({{ attributes.poster }});">
```

I've done the same for Video, i.e. using a separate field for the poster of the html5 video tag, using the same method EXCEPT in the field template #attributes is #player_attributes as you should be able to see in the file twig template, named video-player-formatter.html.twig in my case. Happy to post the code if anyone needs it.

Thanks to the drupal forums, twig documentation and of course stackexchange for the snippets I picked up along the way to figure this out.